# How to add new text box fields on check out web page odoo

Tags: odoo

I want to add add new text box fields for remarks on checkout webpage Odoo.
How should I do for that and then want to show that remarks on payment page also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit website_sale.checkout template.

`<template id="checkout_custom" inherit_id="website_sale.checkout">
    <xpath expr="//input[@name='city']" position="after">
        <input type="remarks" name="remarks" class="form-control"/>
    </xpath>
 </template>`

Comment: thanks, after add some text in this remark, how can I save this remark field.